# Runtime error , bugs and issues iphone App

Tags: ios, xcode, frameworks, revmob

I am trying to add an AdManager File in my iphone app so that it has differernt types of ads. (revmob, adwhirl, chartboost etc). At the same time I want the In App-Purchase functionality as well. I am working correct on that but there is some issues and bugs which I don't understand what are, I even added all the required frameworks.

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
"_OBJC_METACLASS_$_CDataScanner", referenced from:
 _OBJC_METACLASS_$_CJSONScanner in CJSONScanner.o

"_SKStoreProductParameterITunesItemIdentifier", referenced from:
  -[RevMobStoreController openStoreWithITunesItemId:] in RevMobAds(RevMobStoreController.o)

"_OBJC_CLASS_$_SKStoreProductViewController", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in RevMobAds(RevMobStoreController.o)

"_OBJC_IVAR_$_CDataScanner.current", referenced from:
  -[CJSONScanner scanNotQuoteCharactersIntoString:] in CJSONScanner.o

"_OBJC_CLASS_$_CDataScanner", referenced from:
  l_OBJC_$_CATEGORY_CDataScanner_$_CDataScanner_Extensions in CDataScanner_Extensions.o

  _OBJC_CLASS_$_CJSONScanner in CJSONScanner.o
"_OBJC_IVAR_$_CDataScanner.end", referenced from:
  -[CJSONScanner scanNotQuoteCharactersIntoString:] in CJSONScanner.o
```

ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Answer (score 0):

Did you add the StoreKit framework?
That would certainly resolve the first couple of linker errors.